# How to let Users Be Apart Of A Group When They Sign Up for an Account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Hello I need help pushing users into groups when they sign up for an account. After a long hard day I have succeeded in adding the nested attribute of groups to users. But now when I submit my form I get this error...

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch at /users Group(#70300311693200) expected, got ActionController::Parameters(#70300262460820)
```

Here are my models for the project

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
    belongs_to :group
  end

   class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
     validates :name, presence: true
     has_many :users
     default_scope lambda { order('groups.name') }
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
   end
```

Here is my nested attribute view

```
      <div class="form-group">
       <%= f.fields_for :group do |i| %>
         <%= i.label :name %><br />
         <%= i.select :name , Group.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }%></p>
       <% end %>
     </div>
```

And here is my application controller

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
     # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
     # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
     protect_from_forgery with: :exception
     before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

   protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
       devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :first, :last, group:  [:name, :id]) }
       devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :last, :first, :current_password, :password, group:  [:name, :id]) }
      end
   end
```

And Here is My Migration File

```
    class CreateJoinTableUserGroup < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
       create_join_table :users, :groups do |t|
         t.index [:user_id, :group_id]
         t.index [:group_id, :user_id]
       end
     end
   end
```

**Update**

```
  class AddGroupIdToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
       add_column :users, :group_id, :integer
     end
  end
```

All I need is to be able to check my rails console and be able to see if Users are Associated with a Group. If any one can tell me a quick method to do so I would greatly appreciate it. I am using rails 4.1.6 and devise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing you have a **group_id** foreign key on **User** which its value equal to to one of the **Group's** primary id, you should be able to test this relationship on rails console by typing

```
Group.first.users 
       OR
Group.find(ID).users
```

Refer to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association for more info about has_many association

Comment: @uriu I have edited the question again so now it includes the migration file. also say wow this is a great method. Now I know my migration file is wrong or at least needs to be changed up. when running this method I received the errorSQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.group_id: SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."group_id" = ?
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.group_id: SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."group_id" = ?. Also just read the guides and will implement them. what do you think is wrong with the migration file?

Comment: @denzy, your migration code is used to create a join table which is used if you have HABTM relationship. Refer to the updated migration above to create group_id column on User table.

Answer (score 1):

You should have join table for this kind of concept.

As you are using devise for registration and other purpose. You need to override views and controller of devise to make desired changes. Because I think you should add `feilds_for` group on your `sign_up` form to add user in a group.

Comment: At first I did not want to dwell in the devise controllers but I realize I may have to. Do you have experience with the devise controllers? I still feel hesitant to do so and there is really no need to. However I understand it's okay to experiment. I will try to edit the controllers and let you know if it works out for me. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @user3952353 The good news is that I figured out how to include a nested attribute to the devise views however I am now I am now receiving this error. ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch at /users Group(#70300311693200) expected, got ActionController::Parameters(#70300262460820).here is my new code at github https://github.com/DenzzyDrake/Trouper.

Comment: @user3952353 I have now edited the question as well to give a better understanding of what I am looking for as well as the code I edited